# Method overloading getting wrong overload

Tags: vb.net, methods, overloading

I am having a problem convincing Visual Studio and the compiler to use the correct method overload, possibly because of inheritance.

Given these objects:

```
Public Class Matrix
...
End Class

Public Class Vector
Inherits Matrix
...
End Class
```

two methods in a Module exist:

```
Public Function Add(vector1 as Vector, vector2 as Vector) as Vector
...
End Function

Public Function Add(matrix1 as Matrix, matrix2 as Matrix) as Matrix
...
End Function
```

However when I explicitly call Add() on two Vector objects, I get an InvalidCastException because Vector cannot be cast to Matrix to use the Matrix incarnation of the function. I was under the impression the compiler would attempt to use the most specific method possible, thus for these arguments use the Vector method. Additionally if there was any ambiguity the compiler would catch these and provide an error.

1. Is this behaviour to specification?
2. Is it possible to force the usage of the Vector method? I have tried casting both arguments, but since they are dimensioned as Vectors already, it has no effect.

**Edit**: Calling code requested

Note that the two Add methods are in the same Math module, i.e.

```
Public Module Math
    Public Function Add(vector1 as Vector, vector2 as Vector) as Vector
    ...
    End Function

    Public Function Add(matrix1 as Matrix, matrix2 as Matrix) as Matrix
    ...
    End Function

    Public Function Subtract(ByVal vector1 As Vector, ByVal vector2 As Vector) As Vector
        Return Add(vector1, -vector2)
    End Function
End Module
```

Comment: Can you show an example of the code which calls Add().  It may be a problem with how the variables are declared.

Comment: I added the calling code for you. The only link between the two classes is through inheritance.

Comment: Apologies I corrected the calling code to that which was actually causing the problem, and in doing so found my error. The negation operator had lost its overload so -vector2 was reverting to its Matrix base negation operator.

Answer (score 0):

Answers:

1. No it is not; Probably you have more than one Vector or Matrix type object defined in your project. That is why your are getting InvalidCastException.
2. You don't need to.

Comment: I'm not sure how this could be, since same named objects in the same namespace would themselves cause compiler errors and if there were multiple namespaces in the project with the same object then the way they are being referenced would need to be imported would cause a namespace collision.